# How can I influence Graphviz/dot to make nicer control-flow graphs by removing snaking and better edge crossings?

Tags: graphviz, dot, control-flow, control-flow-graph

I am drawing control-flow graphs for Python programs and would like to influence which kind of edges should not be crossed over. Is there a way to do this?

Consider this simple Python program:

```
try:
    a += 1
except:
    a += 2
else:
    a = 3
```

And a dot program to represent the control flow for that generated via https://github.com/rocky/python-control-flow/

```
digraph G {
  mclimit=1.5;
  rankdir=TD; ordering=out;
  graph[fontsize=10 fontname="Verdana"];
  color="#efefef";
  node[shape=box style=filled fontsize=8 fontname="Verdana" fillcolor="#efefef"];
  edge[fontsize=8 fontname="Verdana"];

  node_0 [shape = "oval"][label="Basic Block 0\loffsets: 0..12\lflags=entry, block, unconditional, try\ljumps=[34]\l"];
  node_1 [label="Basic Block 1\loffsets: 14..30\lflags=except, unconditional\ljumps=[38]\l"];
  node_2 [label="Basic Block 2\loffsets: 32..32\lflags=end finally\l"];
  node_3 [label="Basic Block 3\loffsets: 34..36\l"];
  node_4 [label="Basic Block 4\loffsets: 38..40\lflags=no fallthrough\l"];

  node_0 -> node_2 [weight=1][color="red"];
  node_3 -> node_4 [weight=10];
  node_0 -> node_1 [weight=1][color="red"];
  node_2 -> node_3 [weight=10];
  node_0 -> node_1 [weight=10][style="invis"];
  node_1 -> node_2 [weight=10][style="invis"];
  node_1 -> node_4 [weight=1];
  node_0 -> node_3 [weight=1];
}
```

The image that dot produces for the above is [image]

Notice how one line snakes around and crosses a straight arrow down. Instead I would prefer if none of the straight downward arrows would be crossed. Splined edges would make better crossing places.

If you look at the dot, I have two invisible downward edges which I use for alignment. (In the bytecode these follow the linear sequence of instructions).

So if a downward straight line needs to be crossed (and here it doesn't), invisible edges would be preferred over those that are visible.

Thoughts?

**Edit**

The one excellent answer so far suggests changing the order that the edges are defined and specifying in certain situations where edge attachments should be made.

In this application, I do have hierarchical nesting information from a dominator tree, and I can classify the edges: those that loop, those that jump to the end of a compound structure, those that break out a loop, and so on.

So now the problem becomes exactly *how* one uses this information to avoid those snaking arrows, and ensures that breaks out of loops are preferred to cross over edges over say "if"/"else" jump edges.

This feels like VLSI design: come up with a set of patterns that work for each kind of (control-flow) structure and those will then nest and sequence properly.

I have experimented with the edge ordering and placement, and I just don't have an intuitive sense of when to put something earlier or later.

Guidance, or better, a design rule for structured control flow edges would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things to improve the situation:

- draw (one of) the edges that you want to control earlier than the others,
- tell graphviz where you want them to be attached (North, East... )

I have edited your code accordingly

```
digraph G {
  mclimit=1.5;
  rankdir=TD; ordering=out;
  graph[fontsize=10 fontname="Verdana"];
  color="#efefef";
  node[shape=box style=filled fontsize=8 fontname="Verdana" fillcolor="#efefef"];
  edge[fontsize=8 fontname="Verdana"];

  node_0 [shape = "oval"][label="Basic Block 0\loffsets: 0..12\lflags=entry, block, unconditional, try\ljumps=[34]\l"];
  node_1 [label="Basic Block 1\loffsets: 14..30\lflags=except, unconditional\ljumps=[38]\l"];
  node_2 [label="Basic Block 2\loffsets: 32..32\lflags=end finally\l"];
  node_3 [label="Basic Block 3\loffsets: 34..36\l"];
  node_4 [label="Basic Block 4\loffsets: 38..40\lflags=no fallthrough\l"];

  node_0 -> node_3:nw [weight=1];           /* moved up and added directions*/
  node_0 -> node_2 [weight=1][color="red"];
  node_3 -> node_4 [weight=10];
  node_0 -> node_1 [weight=1][color="red"];
  node_2 -> node_3 [weight=10];
  node_0 -> node_1 [weight=10][style="invis"];
  node_1 -> node_2 [weight=10][style="invis"];
  node_1:se -> node_4:ne [weight=1];            /* added directions */
}
```

which gives you

[image]

There's a bit of trial and error involved here but I'm sure this should help.

Comment: This is interesting. I _can_ use the program structure (specifically the dominator tree) to assist me in determining the inner-to-outer structure. But I need to understand how the order changes things. Do I do the inner blocks first, and outer blocks last, or the other way around? Those things that are more okay to cross edges (like a break inside a loop which might cross the inner "if/try" statements) do I render those last? I suppose I could put all of the loop back edges on one side.

Comment: In my prior experiments I was using `[headport=nw, tailport=sw]` instead of the colon thing you have on the node which works better. What's the difference?

Comment: To your first point: I don't have a good answer, and the topic seems to be difficult for [insiders as well](https://github.com/ellson/MOTHBALLED-graphviz/issues/1263). In general, my experience is that edges that are defined earlier have a higher "priority" but that's not real knowledge. To the second point, I believe the "colon thing" is just a shorthand, but again cannot confirm definitely.

Comment: Ok. This is helpful, even if it is what it is. I have been playing around with the layout manually, and I really don't have any good insight as to an algorithmic way to get good output. So I'll leave this unaccepted for a couple of days in case someone else has further detail. Thanks.